# Simplifying development process with ColdFusion

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, coldfusion, development-environment

I am very new to web development. I currently  have the following setup for development and testing:

1. A local development environment which includes a git repo with the code that will eventually go into production.
2. A BitBucket repo which is the `origin` remote for the local git repo.
3. AWS instances which is configured similarly to the production environtment, including ColdFusion, IIS, and MS SQL. This also contains a git repo with the BitBucket repo configured as the `origin` remote.

My current development cycle goes like this:

1. Make changes on my local machine, commit to git, and push to BitBucket.
2. Tab to a Remote Desktop window with a connection to the AWS instance and pull from BitBucket.
3. Tab back to my local machine to run tests against the changes.

This morning I wasted two hours because I forgot step 2. My tests did not display the expected behavior because I was not running against the most recent version of my code. Of course, I learned that I need to double-check what code is on the server before I proceed with any other debugging. At the same time, simplifying the entire configuration will help avoid these problems entirely.

I am looking for options that can help here. My ideas so far are

1. Install a local ColdFusion server so that I can test directly on my development machine. As far as I can tell, this requires buying a license. I have not yet found a free development or community version of the ColdFusion server. Even though development for ColdFusion is a requirement from our customer, the company I work for is unlikely fork out the money for the server for development. This also will require configuring IIS and MS SQL, which is likely a headache.
2. Configure BitBucket to push my changes to the AWS instance instead of the current setup. The problem is that we start new AWS instances every day, so the URLs and IP addresses change. Additionally, BitBucket would need credentials for the AWS instance in order to push the changes. Finally, I will need to find a way to make sure the AWS instance has the current branch checked out in its git repo. If I can solve these issues, this seems good because I can just push to BitBucket and not worry about what version I am running tests against.
3. Add the repo on the AWS instance as a remote to my local repo with `git remote add`. I will need to do this each morning when a new instance is started, which isn't a big deal. The problems I see here are that git will complain if I push to the current branch. Even if I figure out a way around that, how do I ensure that the changes are checked out in the correct folder where IIS expects to find it?

It seems to me that the underlying problem is not specific to the particular tools I am using but is part of web development in general. What are common approaches to making development as fluid as possible?

Comment: Too much tech, get yourself a to-do list, a paper one, and a pencil.  If a to-do list doesn't appeal call it a checklist and imagine you are either the pilot of a large commercial airliner or a brain surgeon.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the development stack you're using (ColdFusion, et al) I can at least comment on the process.  It's highly unusual for a target server to *pull* code, especially from source control itself.  Generally the developer would locally interact with source control and locally dev/debug/test as much as possible.  Then when it's time to deploy to a target environment, the developer would perform a deployment to *push* a deployable instance to that target.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I do not understand how your suggestion addresses my question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: *This morning I wasted two hours because I forgot step 2.*  Not something that would have happened had you been following a list.  And bear in mind, my comment is a comment, I don't pretend it is an answer.

Comment: @David Developing and testing locally definitely seems ideal. In this case, that will require buying a Cold Fusion license, which I do not think the company will do. From what I understand, we are using AWS instances for development for financial reasons. Someone decided this would be cheaper than buying a license.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I understand now. You are suggesting writing a list of the steps I need to take during my development cycle much like a pilot does when prepping for takeoff or landing. That definitely makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: And that's certainly not as uncommon as I might like, licensing does often impose such restrictions.  All it really does is add significant time to a developer's feedback cycle.  Replacing local debugging with remote deployment and logging adds time and effort.  But ultimately I would think the series of steps would be the same.  Deploy from the development workstation, rather than "pull" from the target environment.  In a well enough designed system, there can even be automated deployments upon committing code.

Comment: @David I really don't need BitBucket as a middle-man. Pushing directly to an AWS instance could be a possible third-option. In that case, I need to figure out put the current version in the IIS root directory. AFAIK, I cannot push there directly because git won't allow me to push to the current branch.

Comment: When @David is talking about 'pushing' to a server, he doesn't mean he's using `git` to do any sort of pushing. Today's web dev environment is typically more complex that just here are your individual css/html/js files. There are usually database updates, SASS integrations, js minification, etc... that need to take place between the 'code' being checked-in (commited/pushed) and deploying your end product...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Adobe offers a free developer edition of Cold Fusion for testing locally. It only allows access from 2 remote IPs though. You can sign up for the download off of this page: http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html

Comment: I can answer part of your question; ColdFusion actually is available for free. So there are two main _flavors_ of ColdFusion available - Lucee and Adobe. The Lucee version (formerly Railo) is open source and as such completely free. The other version is Adobe's. The way their license works is that you need to pay for any versions running on production servers. Otherwise you are free to install the software on development servers/workstations as you wish. They are fully functional but limited in the number of allowed connections.

Comment: @Charles Wow! I read that page several times over the last two weeks. I missed that Free Developer version at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Miguel-F Thanks for the information! I was only unaware of Adobe ColdFusion, not the Lucee version.

Comment: NP. [Lucee](http://lucee.org/). And by the way, I do know many ColdFusion developers that work as you mentioned. Develop locally on their workstation and then push code to the server. I'm a bit old school and use development servers. Just modify the code directly on the server (via mapped drives) and then refresh browser, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Charles After signing up for a Adobe ID then clicking the Download button, I got a 404 error. ;-( I'll check it out again later when I have some more time.

Comment: You can also download CommandBox (https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox) and it can start up ad-hoc CF servers on demand.

Comment: Yep what @beloitdavisja said and it also has integrations with various repositories including git.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's weird. For me it went to the 30 day free trial, which I believe reverts to their developer mode when it expires. Of course they wanted a bunch of contact info before even letting me get to the download.

Comment: Since I can only add one vote for CommandBox, I'm going to recommend it again here. It makes a lot of this stuff much easier.

Comment: If it's true that you can push to amazon, I would consider the following: 
`origin` is a standard name for something called upstream. To your repository you can add as many upstreams as you want. One, default one, can be called `origin` and goes to bitbucket and then you can add another one perhaps called `aws1` that goes to your current aws instance.
`git remote add [upstream_name] amazonurl`. Although not very practical if you start a new instance everyday, it still takes just one extra command.

Comment: Continued: Type `git remote -v` on your command line to see all the upstreams for your repository. -- Hope this helps.

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo Thanks for the suggestion. Pushing directly to the AWS instance seems like a reasonable solution. It removes one step from my current process. The only issue I see is that the AWS instance does not have a bare repo and by default git will not allow me to push to the current branch of a remote. Even if I get around issue, how do I ensure that the changes to the pushed branch end up in the correct directory on the AWS server?

Comment: @Charles Revisiting this today and I noticed "Adobe ColdFusion Express Edition" right next to "Adobe ColdFusion Developer Edition" on the link you gave earlier. Right below the paragraph describing "Adobe ColdFusion Express Edition" there are links for direct downloads of this product. I completely overlooked this all the other times I visited this page.